# When Is obtainPermanentIDsForObjects:error: ever needed? from 2 different classes?

Tags: ios, core-data, nsmanagedobjectcontext

My understanding on the background of using this (2 different versions which varies on return values) method is: Managed-Objects created in memory by a MOC are first assigned temporary object IDs so that they may be uniquely identified without involving the persistent store. When a MOC is saved, however, the persistent store coordinator needs permanent object IDs for these Managed-objects. (correct me if I got wrong, please!)

I never used MOC's

```
- (BOOL)obtainPermanentIDsForObjects:(NSArray *)objects error:(NSError **)error
```

, but still call MOC's save: method without problems. However the code I used this week by 3rd party, uses this MOC's obtainPermanentIDsForObjects each time right after inserting a new Managed-object, is this really necessary?? Maybe needed for multithreading environment? But why Apple "CoreData PG" never mentioned this method? Has persistent-store-coordinator done it automatically for me just before saving MOC?

During research I saw another version of this method in NSIncrementalStore Class...

```
- (NSArray *)obtainPermanentIDsForObjects:(NSArray *)array error:(NSError **)error
```

, it says "This method is called (overridden in subclass then called, I guess) before executeRequest:withContext:error: with a save request, to assign permanent IDs to newly-inserted objects."

What should I do? Do I need to use both versions (NSIncrementalStore subclass's before save, and MOC's version right after new creation)? Which method is must called OR neither?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When an `NSManagedObject` is first inserted into an `NSManagedObjectContext` it has a temporary `NSManagedObjectID`. When the context is saved, the `NSManagedObjectContext` will do the equivalent of `obtainPermanentIDsForObjects:error` on `NSManagedObjectContext`, which in turn calls `NSPersistentStoreCoordinator`, which finds the store responsible for this object and calls `obtainPermanentIDsForObjects:error` on the store itself. This turns the `NSManagedObject`'s temporary ID into a permanent one.

`NSManagedObjectID`s can be passed between `NSManagedObjectContext`s (if they share the same stores), but only if the `NSManagedObjectID` is a permanent ID. You *can* call `obtainPermanentIDsForObjects:error` to turn a temporary ID into a permanent ID independent of a save operation, but the store that the object belongs to may not expect that.

Comment: Thanks @quellish! therefore, in order to pass NSManagedObjectID between MOCs, I'd better call this method without relying on any MOC's save operation

Comment: It's preferable to save rather than calling this method directly. Create a new child context, set the parent, insert your object and save in the child. The object will be pushed to the parent and no further. Discard the child if you want.

Comment: are there any situations in which calling this method is a good fit?

Comment: Not really. It's always preferable to save rather than call this method directly. You can always create a throwaway context to do so.

Comment: You @quellish, are my favorite here at StackOverFlow. Reading your answers is EVEN more helpful than Apple doc! Do you have a website ?

Comment: quellish.tumblr.com . Working on several iOS books but no ETA yet.

Comment: Hurry up bro! Before Swift mature release comes up in the next 18-24 months, I bet your book will be a big hit, it MUST attracts lots lots of readers. Focusing on security, concurrency and networking issues may give longer life to your book. Thanks for your help!!!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/58923/discussion-between-j-q-and-quellish).